# How to call this type of async function in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How to type an async callback function in onAuthStateChanged?

There is an error "Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected." from this line.

```
async (user: User | null) => {
  const unpdatedUser = user ? await adminUser(user) : null;
  callback(unpdatedUser);
};
```

here is the full code.

```
type DispatchType = Dispatch<SetStateAction<User | null>>;

export function onUserStateChange(callback: DispatchType) {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user: User | null) => {
    const unpdatedUser = user ? await adminUser(user) : null;
    callback(unpdatedUser);
  });
}

async function adminUser(user: User | null) {
  return get(ref(database, 'admins')).then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      const admins = snapshot.val();
      const isAdmin = admins.include(user?.uid);
      return { ...user, isAdmin };
    }
    return user;
  });
}
```

Comment: Async functions always return a promise. If you're expecting `void`, then use `Promise<void>`.    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#:~:text=Async%20functions%20always%20return%20a%20promise.

Comment: _"from this line"_... which of those four lines is _"this line"_?

Comment: What is `onAuthStateChanged`? What type of callback does it expect?

Comment: @Bergi `onAuthStateChanged`, `get` and `ref` all point to Firebase

Answer (score 0):

You've got some type confusion around the Firebase Auth `User` type and your own `User` type that includes an `isAdmin` Boolean.

I'd go with something like this...

```ts
import { User as FirebaseUser } from "firebase/auth";

// this is your user type
interface User extends FirebaseUser {
  isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

You should also check for a `null` `user` parameter before attempting to spread it into `{ ...user, isAdmin }`.

Your `adminUser` function should return type `Promise<User | null>`

```ts
async function adminUser(user: FirebaseUser | null): Promise<User | null> {
  // null user
  if (!user) {
    return user;
  }

  const isAdmin =
    (await get(ref(database, "admins"))).val()?.include(user.uid) ?? false;
  return { ...user, isAdmin };
}
```